# Cannot create Xamarin.Android Java Bindings Library for Microsoft Engagement Insights SDK

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, dynamics-365, java-binding

I am trying to integrate Android SDK for Microsoft Customer Insights Engagement Insights in my Xamarin Android app and would need to create a Xamarin.Android Java Bindings Library since the SDK provides a pre-release aar file.

I created an Android Bindings Library(Xamarin) project, added eiandroidsdk-debug.aar and followed the steps mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/binding-an-aar) for creating the dll file. I am running into below errors while building:

`\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Microsoft.Engagementinsights.Transmission.Core.InternalMgrImpl.cs(78,76,78,90): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'EventMessenger' does not exist in the namespace 'Com.Microsoft.Engagementinsights.Transmission.Core' \obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Microsoft.Engagementinsights.Transmission.Core.ITransmissionEvents.cs(13,130,13,148): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'RecordWithMetadata' does not exist in the namespace 'Com.Microsoft.Engagementinsights.Transmission.Core' \obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Microsoft.Engagementinsights.Transmission.Core.ITransmissionEvents.cs(17,127,17,145): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'RecordWithMetadata' does not exist in the namespace 'Com.Microsoft.Engagementinsights.Transmission.Core' \obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Microsoft.Engagementinsights.Transmission.Core.ITransmissionEvents.cs(21,129,21,147): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'RecordWithMetadata' does not exist in the namespace 'Com.Microsoft.Engagementinsights.Transmission.Core' \obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Microsoft.Engagementinsights.Transmission.Core.ITransmissionEvents.cs(25,121,25,139): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'RecordWithMetadata' does not exist in the namespace 'Com.Microsoft.Engagementinsights.Transmission.Core' \obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Microsoft.Engagementinsights.Transmission.Core.ITransmissionEvents.cs(103,144,103,162): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'RecordWithMetadata' does not exist in the namespace 'Com.Microsoft.Engagementinsights.Transmission.Core' \obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Microsoft.Engagementinsights.Transmission.Core.ITransmissionEvents.cs(136,141,136,159): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'RecordWithMetadata' does not exist in the namespace 'Com.Microsoft.Engagementinsights.Transmission.Core' \obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Microsoft.Engagementinsights.Transmission.Core.ITransmissionEvents.cs(170,143,170,161): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'RecordWithMetadata' does not exist in the namespace 'Com.Microsoft.Engagementinsights.Transmission.Core' \obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Microsoft.Engagementinsights.Transmission.Core.ITransmissionEvents.cs(203,135,203,153): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'RecordWithMetadata' does not exist in the namespace 'Com.Microsoft.Engagementinsights.Transmission.Core'`

It seems like 2 of the referred files are not generated:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Raised an issue on sdk github page as well: https://github.com/microsoft/engagementinsights-sdk-android/issues/1

I tried targeting Android SDK 10 and 11 both but no effect. Does anyone have any idea if there is something wrong with the aar file or am I missing something in binding process?

Comment: The steps seems ok. Please check it again. You could also check the code sample for binding arr. https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/JavaIntegration/AarBinding

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT Tried again fresh and ran into the same issue. I also tried with textanalyzer.aar provided in the sample and it works just fine, so the problem seems to be with the engagement insights aar.

Comment: You could generate a new aar to check.

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT Engagement Insights SDK is not open source, so I can't create a new aar myself. I hope that the issue will be resolved once a stable version of SDK is out.

Comment: You could your requirement in the link below. https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues